# Google map in jquery mobile works when going directly to page but not when navigating from another page

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get google maps to display on a jquery mobile page.

The map works fine if I type I go directly to the page in the browser. However, when I click a link on another jqm page that goes to the map page, I just get a blank grey screen. The markers are actually there but they are plotted off the viewable area above and to the left of the viewport. Also weird is that I am able to drag on the canvas and bring the markers into view in a small, invisible viewport in the upper left hand corner (probably about 100 px wide and 200 px high), but I can't see the actual map.

Here's a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8berda8dbf6kh4/Screenshot%202015-05-25%2014.24.15.png?dl=0

If I immediately refresh the page after the failed load, everything shows up fine. So I don't think this is an API issue.

And one other oddity. If I wait like 10 min, the map will load properly when I click on the link to view the map. But then the next time I try it fails to load. I have to wait several minutes.

My code is basically ripped right from the jquery mobile site. Here's the relevant code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=MY_KEY"></script>

        <!-- JQM and other scripts loaded here -->

<script>
    $( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#map", function() {
    var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.0983425, -118.3267434); 
    drawMap(defaultLatLng);

    function drawMap(latlng) {
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
      new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "lat",
      });
      new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.150358,-74.768798),
         map: map,
         title: 'hello',
      });
    }
});
</script>

<style>
    #map, #map-canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; }
</style>

   </head>
   <body>
       #calling page
       <div data-role="page" data-dom-cache="true" id="doors" data-url="doors" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active" style="position: relative; min-height: 559px;">
           <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="">
               <a href="#map" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini" id="view_map_btn" data-ajax="false">View map</a>
           </div>
       </div>

       #map page
       <div data-role="page" id="map" data-url="map" style="position: relative;">
           <div data-role="header" data-theme="a"><h1>Maps</h1></div><div role="main" class="ui-content" id="map-canvas">
           </div>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after hours of banging my head against a wall I finally got it working by changing from `pagecreate` to `pageshow`. Interestingly `pageshow` is deprecated in v. 1.4.5 and is supposed to be replaced by `pagecontainershow` but `pagecontainershow` does not work.

And as usual, I find the answer within minutes of posting the question.